timestamp header value getting replaced at consumer
I have a kafka producer sending data using KafkaTemplate.send(). In the ProducerRecord, I add a header with key timestamp and add a custom timestamp value. I have a consumer consuming records using @KafkaListener to ConsumerRecord object.
When I try to access the timestamp header from this consumer record, I get the value whatever I send from producer.
Now I have one more consumer written using Consumer<Message<String>> as a bean. Here the kafka configurations are done using kafka binding(spring.cloud.stream.kafka). When I extract the timestamp header from the received Message object, the value is different than I send from producer.
How can I fix this? Is there any way I can reuse the original timestamp key and keep the custom timestamp value?

Because the timestamp header of the Message is auto-generated and represents the time of message creation. It has nothing to do with your logic. It's a property of a Message. in fact there are two, timestamp and id and you have no control of it. You can find your own in other headers that were copied from ProducerRecord

You shouldn't need a header at all. Kafka has had timestamps as part of the record before headers were introduced. The Message envelope doesn't parse the headers, per my understanding
